# Carbohydrates percentage in lacto fermented potatoes

Tags: potatoes, fermentation, keto

I am wondering: how much carbs do lacto fermented potatoes contain? Or how would one determine that?

### Context

I am into keto diet since it has been like a miracle when it comes to weight loss for me in the past and it's just about time for me to come back to it. I am trying to make it more interesting than fried meat with cheese and mayonnaise this time and I know that during lacto fermentation carbs are consumed by bacteria. I have tried lacto fermenting pickles and it was extremely easy with really great results - I just added 2.5% (of total weight) salt to pickles in water weighted them down so they don't rise above water and forgot it for a few weeks and it all turned out really well. So now I am thinking about how much I like fried potatoes and if I could just ferment them in exactly same manner to get rid of the carbs. I would use the same process with 2.5% salt with peeled and sliced (and well washed) raw potatoes. I am wondering how sure I can be that most of carbs would be gone after this process.

I would appreciate any extra advice on the whole process, but keeping in mind the style of Stack Exchange platform I am looking for an answer about carbohydrate amount based on facts or direct experience(I have no idea how testing or calculating these things work).

Comment: Given that potatoes are carbs surrounded by a cellulose skin I'm not sure what you expect to be left after all the carbs have been consumed.

Comment: That's a very good point, however, searching online, I find cases where people do lacto ferment potatoes. That's why the question -  I do not know what I could expect to be left. :D

Comment: I guess, I expect few percent of proteins, that cellulose, 0.1% fat, various vitamins, minerals like potassium, lots of water, lactic acid and the lacto fermenting bacteria themselves. Maybe they are delicious - what do I know?..

Comment: @GdD, thanks, that is actually a really good perspective of looking at it. The very interesting thing is if I try searching for lacto fermented pickles nutrition. There is really nothing much in them either and they are delicious. Maybe there is hope for potatoes still.

Answer (score 4):

Lacto-fermenting potatoes, like lacto-fermenting other vegetables (like cucumbers), will only very slightly reduce the amount of  carbohydrates they contain. After that, the lactic acid buildup will kill the bacteria.  But while most vegetables have only a small percentage of digestible carbohydrates to begin with (they’re mostly water and dietary fiber), potatoes are made almost entirely of carbohydrates and water. So they’ll still, nutritionally, be potatoes once fermented.